# How to check if the specific file exists on server every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript

I am maintaining an auto server that converts xml files into .key files every 5 minutes. If I paste the xml files into the "IN" folder then it will generate the key for all xml files and get moved into the "OUT" folder every 5 minutes. This is my process.

Now my requirement is, how can I get the notification about the xml files that are moved into "OUT" folder from "IN" folder using java script?

Comment: Did you try something? Please post some code, it will be easier to help you out. I will not do it for you.

Comment: I am new to javascript So please help me . I can understand from code

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   // Do whatever you want
}, 300000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval() function and call ajax for checking file on server

```
setInterval(function(){ 

// Ajax code here

},300000)
```

300000 (milliseconds) is the time interval on which you want to call the ajax method

time is in milliseconds here